# add new button / links on hover over on kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

Is there a way to add links or buttons when you hover over a row on a kendo grid?  I looked in the documentation and googled for a bit, but I could not find anything.  I wasn't sure if I just needed to have my row template be able to show/hide my button/links based on hover over or if kendo grids had something out of the box that would make this easier.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

Comment: Do you mean dynamically add/show buttons when you place mouse over a row?

Comment: @OnaBai Yup, that's what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing out-of-the-box but you can do almost everything.

Lets assume that you want to show a standard button (ex: `edit` or `destroy`). Then your column definition is something like this:

```
columns   : [
    { command: [ "edit", "destroy" ] },
    // Other column definition
    ...
]
```

Next is hiding every button inside this grid identified by `grid`.

```
#grid .k-button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then add a new style for making it visible when the mouse is over it:

```
#grid .k-button.showme {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Finally we have to add some handling code for controlling when the mouse is over the row. This is the tricky part:

1. It cannot be done via CSS (i.e. using :hover) because we want to control when the mouse is over the row but we want to change (add a CSS class) to the button.
2. Since the grid might be redraw (when you sort, paginate,...) we need to use `live` event handlers.

So what we do is when the mouse enters a row, we add `showme` class (make button visible).

```
$(grid.tbody).on("mouseenter", "tr", function (e) {
    $(".k-button", e.currentTarget).addClass("showme");
});
```

When the mouse exits the row, we remove `showme` class.

```
$(grid.tbody).on("mouseleave", "tr", function (e) {
    console.log("exit");
    $(".k-button", e.currentTarget).removeClass("showme");
});
```

And here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/BjuVr/) a running example.